# Server error occurred at DriveApp.createFile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, server-error

Every time I'm trying to manually invoke this test function in my script I get `Server Error occurred. Please wait and try again` (in a red bar on top of the editor window).

My original intention was to save a blob with `createFile(blob)` in my Web App, but it just fails with no error output, so I created this minimal test function.

```js
function testgdrive()
{
  var gdrive_file = 
  DriveApp.createFile("testfile","testcontents",MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

EDIT: This happens **both** on old **Rhino** engine and the new **V8** engine as well.

The Web App is being deployed as a Google Sheets script on my basic (free) GSuite account.

It is a Google Cloud project, as I wasn't able to get any logs for Web App executions in the Standard mode at all.

Comment: Add  more details like the runtime that you are using (new/V8 or old / Rhino), if you are using the default Google Cloud Project or a Standard project, if you are using a free Google account or a G Suite account, if this code is on a standalone or a bounded project, how you are calling the function.

Comment: Try  creating a new project.

Comment: Thank you, @TheMaster, it works in another (non-GSuite) account.

Comment: Hi ! @TheMaster ! Could you formalise your comment into an answer as it seems it solved the original poster's question? In that way users with similar issues will find the answer in an easier way (rather than having to look through the comments). Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Done(but I'm literally posting a layman solution: "Did you turn it off and on again?")

Answer (score 1):

For server errors such as

> Server Error occurred. Please wait and try again

Creating/switching over to a new project may resolve the issue.